# Documentation drafts are not saved

Tags: bug, status-completed, documentation, documentation-topics, documentation-drafts

I just lost a draft of a piece I was putting together for C++11 / OpenGL and RAII idiom. I have no idea of what happened to it. I don't know why it showed up in the 'examples' as I was working on it, only to find it missing the next day.

I don't know if anyone has the moderator tools to recover it, but if I don't have time to do it in one sitting, I'm not risking it again.

What am I failing to understand? Why can't my drafts just show up until I'm ready to publish?

Comment: You mean [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/opengl/drafts/95901)?

Comment: I think yes, it is Documentation. I have same problem. I lost my changes few times.  While i was documenting, the draft version is not available when i come later, but still there is "Save as draft" option. At this moment my practise is Document separately in local machine, then paste in Stackoverflow.

Comment: Not to mention.. when you need to add images while drafting the document, you need to save the draft each time you add the image. Else the second image wont be added.  Serious unhappy user experience.

Comment: @user That's odd. Auto-saving should still work regardless. We'll investigate what's going on.

Comment: @EdCottrell - yes, that was it. Except my example (draft) is nowhere to be seen. Thanks for taking a look, mods. I appreciate this  is still in beta.

Comment: @BrettHale What was in your draft? Just a new example or did you edit any other sections of the topic?

Comment: @user Would you mind posting the image-adding bug separately, along with a description of what happens if you don't explicitly hit "save" after adding the second image? Is it just missing from the draft when you open it later, or...? Thanks!

Comment: Yes I can do that as a separate bug. Will post my link here shortly

Comment: @AdamLear - yes it was just a new example. While I have a link to 'created draft' action, the example isn't there. It might be lost. But at least its' revealed a bug.

Comment: @BrettHale Yeah, in your case unfortunately there's no new example draft in the DB. Might be that what I thought was the cause here (see my answer) wasn't what actually happened. I'll try to reproduce this again on Monday, but in the meantime, if you don't mind trying again and letting me know if you hit any issues, that'd be very helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think I found the issue. A bit of refactoring done a few days ago introduced a bug in validating example move state (specifically, for examples that haven't been moved :)). The overall effect was basically that we lost the ability to correctly apply changes in the draft to the topic. The good news is that as far as I can tell, this was only a display issue and all the changes should still be there if you still have your draft handy.

A fix is rolling out now.